# Appending to a list within a subdocument within a list within a document?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoEngine in Python to work with my data model.

I have a data model which essentially looks like this as represented in BSON:

```
{
   'id': ...
   'revisions': [
       {
          'id': ...
          'revision': 1,
          'derivatives': [
              {
                  'id': ... 
                  'name': 'Derivative 1'
              }
          ]
       }
   ]
}
```

We'll call the outermost document the `owner`, all subdocuments in `owner.revisions` will be called `revision`, and all subdocuments in `revision.derivatives` will be called `derivative`.

I'm looking to `$addToSet` to the `derivatives` set inside a specific `revision` inside of a specific `owner`. If I had to write this in Python, it'd look like this:

```
def add_to_set(owner_id, revision_id, new_derivative):
    for owner in owner_collection:
       if owner.id == owner_id:
           # found the right owner
           for revision in owner.revisions:
               if revision.id == revision_id:
                   # we've found the right revision in the right owner
                   # now append and get out
                   revision.derivatives.append(new_derivative)
                   return
```

How can I run this kind of query, selecting the right `revision` inside of the right `owner` and atomically appending to the inner `derivatives` collection on that `revision`?

Having a hard time figuring out how to get started with an update query like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using save based on an older version of the object - it's not thread-safe.

You want to use `update` operator which atomically manipulates an object based on matched condition, rather than unilaterally overwrite an object (by _id) with an entire new object.

Example of unsafe "save":

Thread 1: reads object with field `{_id:1, a:1}`, increments a,  saves `{_id:1,a:2}`
Thread 2: reads object with field `{_id:1, a:1}`, increments a,  saves `{_id:1,a:2}`

Contrast this with "safe" update:

Thread 1: updates object matching `{_id:1}`using operator `{$inc:{a:1}}`
Thread 2: updates object matching `{_id:1}`using operator `{$inc:{a:1}}`

No matter what order the two threads execute in in the second case the value of a will be 2 (since it will be incremented by 1 twice on the server.

I'm guessing the same thing is happening with your object - the analogous update operation you want is [`$push` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

Comment: Can you provide an actual example? I'm not sure how to proceed. I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm aware of _why_ the problem is happening, I'm just not sure how to implement the solution.

Comment: you cannot use save and have it be thread safe unless you implement some sort of locking on the application side.  The alternative would be to switch to using "update" instead of "save"